# How can messages be scripted whenever I open a specific application?

Tags: macos, applescript

Say I want to start Safari on my Mac. Can I create a pop up message that reads, "Use Chrome instead" or some other thing?

I presume it may be possible with Applescript or something, but don't know where to start on teaching myself how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`* * * * * pgrep -xq Safari && terminal-notifier -title 'Click to quit Safari and open Chrome' -message '' -group cronsafari -activate com.google.Chrome -execute 'osascript -e "quit app \"Safari\""' > /dev/null`

The command is run about once per minute, and the notifications are shown repeatedly as long as there is a process named Safari.

You can install terminal-notifier with `sudo gem install terminal-notifier`.